# Htaccess URI images

Tags: image, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to use RewriteTule this simple way

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1`

but I am having a trouble with this:

When I go to a url like:  "empresa/premios" the images, css and other files are searched inside a folder called "empresa". Whaterver URL I try to use the images and other files are always looked up inside a folder with the name on the first parte of the url. In this case, "empresa".

Comment: You need to use absolute URLs for css/images/js.

Comment: I know if I use the absolute path it will work, but I need to work inside my computer and the www folder has other websites.

Comment: Absolute URL means something like `/css/style.css`

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ ./public/images/$1
  RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ ./public/css/$1
  RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ ./public/js/$1

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I tried to use your solution but it doesnt works. This website is inside a folder on my computer (www/m2/), so if I could redirect only the files as I have noticed that you suggest with the code above, it would be great.

Comment: Please use 
RewriteBase /m2

Comment: I do this. But unfortunately it still doesn't makes any difference.
This is the real code I am using:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /m2

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?cod=$1 [L]

This is the url "localhost/m2/nada/teste/".
So, the image inside the file index.php is being searched inside a folder called "nada". The files are inside m2.